# How to place textview in relative layout at random position of the layout?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I am facing the issue to place the textview on the `random position` in relative layout dynamically. The total count of textview can be 1, 3 , 4 ...or 30. It depend on the array list.

I want to put `text view randomly in relative layout`. Please guide me to achive it.

Comment: Plese show us what you have done so far.

Comment: How is this related to design patterns? :D

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
   TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Random random = new Random();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    int random_width = random.nextInt(metrics.widthPixels - 
    textView.getWidth());
    int random_height = random.nextInt(metrics.heightPixels - 
    textView.getHeight());

    if (random_width > (metrics.widthPixels - 100)) {
        random_width -= 100;
    }

    if (random_height > (metrics.heightPixels - 200)) {
        random_height -= 200;
    }
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutParams.width = metrics.widthPixels;
    layoutParams.height = metrics.heightPixels;

    layoutParams.setMargins(random_width, random_height, 0, 0);
    textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutParams.width = metrics.widthPixels;
    layoutParams.height = metrics.heightPixels;


    layoutParams.setMargins(random_width, random_height, 0, 0);
    textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

and in your xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"       
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HI"
        android:textColor="#ff9999" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks @mohammadReza Abiri , I have implemented it. It is working but sometime Textview displaying at out of the layout/screen. And sometimes it overlapping eachother. Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you next approach:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
Random random = new Random();
int num_textViews= 10;
for (int i = 0; i < num_textViews; ++i) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setX(random.nextInt(relativeLayout.getMeasuredWidth()));
    textView.setY(-random.nextInt(relativeLayout.getMeasuredHeight()));
    relativeLayout.addView(textView);
}
```

Comment: Using the display size instead of just using the measured width and height of the RelativeLayout surely will lead to some weird bugs at some point.

Comment: @Shadkirill I have implemented this. But getting error like this `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive`. How can I resolve this?

Comment: @Chirag Pragapati You should do it when your layout was already measured. So try move your code to onResume() method of your Activity.

Comment: Thanks @Shadkirill , I have implemented `mohammadReza Abiri's` answer. It is working but sometime Textview displaying at out of the layout/screen. And sometimes it overlapping eachother. Can you please help

Comment: @ChiragPrajapati try use random.nextInt(relativeLayout.getMeasuredWidth()) and -random.nextInt(relativeLayout.getMeasuredHeight()) to solve the first problem. And to solve the second problem you should save already generated positions of textViews and check if newely generated positions does not overlapping already generated positions.

Comment: Try to use in your onResume:
 
 

relativeLayout.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         int w = relativeLayout.getMeasuredWidth();
         int h = relativeLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
         ...
     }
 });